# Регулярка, которая строго матчит определенное количество цифр

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка, которая находит номера телефонов.

```
((\+7)|8)?[\s-]?\(?9\d{2}\)?[\s-]?(\d{3})([\s-]?\d{2}){2}
```

Это выражение также вылавливает номера договоров вида "8910 11111111" Этот номер матчится, хоть и в нем больше чисел чем в номере телефона. Что добавить, чтобы матчились строго числа с 10 и 11 знаками. То есть 12 и более не заватывает, а 10 и 11 захватывает.

$ в конце не подходит. так как необходимо вылавливать номера телефона, которые могут быть записаны в строку

Comment: *Это выражение также вылавливает номера договоров вида "8910 11111111"* Не всё - последний символ не входит в найденное. Добавьте ограничение (начало-конец строки/текста) `^((\+7)|8)?[\s-]?\(?9\d{2}\)?[\s-]?(\d{3})([\s-]?\d{2}){2}$`. Ну или в крайнем случае [^\d] на хвост повесьте.

Comment: $ в конце не подходит. так как необходимо вылавливать номера телефона, которые могут быть записаны в строку
а вот за  [^\d] спасибо большое!

Comment: Учтите, что следующий символ, который не-цифирь, может оказаться и первым плюсом следующего телефона... маловероятно, конечно, но жизнь - она богаче фантазии. К тому же на хвост нужно по-хорошему вешать `([^\d]|$)` - а ну как строка этим телефоном заканчивается...

Comment: Вот поэтому я задал вопрос, как обозначить строгое количество знаков.. прошу подсказать как это сделать...

Comment: Шаблон всегда создаётся под исчерпывающий набор возможных вариантов. Или, по крайней мере, когда есть гарантия, что два выделенных шаблоном набора не пересекутся. В Вашем случае обозначение "строгого количества знаков" - это указание, что следующий знак соответствует или не соответствует шаблону. Т.е. если после последних двух цифр телефона не-цифра, то всё отлично, а если цифра - то не пойдёт. И вот этот символ, что после последней цифры, тоже должен тестироваться шаблоном. На случай, когда введено +79101111111+79102222222, без пробелов, в шаблонах есть возврат. И - не подскажу, не спец...

Comment: Проверка *перед* номером нужна? Если нет, `(?:\+7|8)?[\s-]?\(?9\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}(?:[\s-]?\d{2}){2}(?!\d)` должно подойти. В начале много необязательных шаблонов, из-за них не очень красивое выражение может получиться. `(?<!\d)(?:\+7|8)?[\s-]?\(?9\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}(?:[\s-]?\d{2}){2}(?!\d)`, может, сработает.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, за красотой не гонюсь. выражение необходимо для политики DLP системы. Второе Ваше выражение с проверкой перед номером?

Answer (score 0):

Следующее регулярное выражение (немного доработал Ваше) точно подходит для проверки номеров вида:

- 89xxxxxxxxx
- 8 9xx xxx xxxx
- +79xxxxxxxxx
- 79xxxxxxxxx
- 7(9xx)xxxxxxx
- текст89xxxxxxxxx
- 926-303-32-31
- 79xxxxxxxxx 79xxxxxxxxx (комментарий ниже).

`((((\+7)|7|8))?[ -]?|)\(?9\d{2}\)?[\s-]?(\d{3})([\s-]?\d{2}){2}\b`

`\b` означает границу слова.

Также вначале применена конструкция `(?(1)yes|no)`

В случае 9xxxxxxxxx 9xxxxxxxxx во втором номере необходимо обрезать нулевой символ (захватывает пробел).

[Пример](https://regex101.com/r/ubISWf/2).

Comment: Необходим матчинг 926-303-32-31
Также просьба пояснить назначение \b

Comment: Внес изменения для определения указанного номера. И еще незначительно доработал.

Answer (score 0):

Немного улчшит ситуацию проверка, что за номером не идёт цифра:

```
((\+7)|8)?[\s-]?\(?9\d{2}\)?[\s-]?(\d{3})([\s-]?\d{2}){2}(?!\d)
```

Если используемый язык поддерживает предпросмотр назад, то стоит ещё добавить, чтобы сов падению не предшествовала цифра:

```
(?<!\d)((\+7)|8)?[\s-]?\(?9\d{2}\)?[\s-]?(\d{3})([\s-]?\d{2}){2}(?!\d)
```

Ну и можно сделать то же самое без предпросмотров, но получив лишние символы, которые придётся потом обрезать взяв первую группу:

```
(?:^|\D)(((\+7)|8)?[\s-]?\(?9\d{2}\)?[\s-]?(\d{3})([\s-]?\d{2}){2})(?:\D|$)
```